# Asymptotic behavior of the solution of a 2nd order linear ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

In studying the harmonic oscillator, we encounter the equation

$$ f'' +(2E - x^2) f = 0$$

What is the asymptotic behaviour of the solution to this equation for a generic $E$?

Any good book on such kind of problems?

Comment: You tagged this as asymptotics, so are you interested in large E, small E, or large $x$, small $x$, or...?  What kind of constraints do you have (boundary, initial, etc.)?

Comment: a finite E; large x.